# Google Workspace Essentials Starter with pp.ua domain

Tags: google-workspace

I'm trying to sign up for Google Workspace Essentials Starter with a "private person" `*.pp.ua` domain, which is free to use in my country. I have a new one just registered and set up at zoho.com free plan account.

After completing several steps on account creation, I'm facing the page saying:

> Sorry, we can't complete your signup
>
> Google works hard to keep spammers from using Google Workspace. As part of this effort, we refuse to create domains that we believe will be used for spam. Unfortunately, we may sometimes refuse legitimate signups. If you've been stopped in error, we're sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> Google weighs several factors when evaluating registration attempts, including the number of domains that have been created from that location and whether the domains have just been created or have a good reputation on the internet. Users trying to create a lot of domains, who are using shared computers or computers infected with malware; or signing up for low reputation domains may hit this limit.

Also, I have an old domain in `*.pp.ua`, which hasn't been used before and failed that check the same way. Can't find any reason why my domain can't pass that check nor any documentation regarding this issue. So any clue is highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the answer is kind of **just because**, but maybe I'm just missing something in DNS records set etc.